# How to perform log time scale fft in matlab?

Tags: matlab, logging, fft

I have data in **log(time)** domain (as picture shows), because fft always use in **time** domain only, then how can I use fft in matlab to transform log(time) data. thx [w(z)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2rZG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. resample to linear time,
2. interpolate to a uniformly spaced data,
3. fft.

You can do 1-2 using the build in `interp1`